# With a linked object, why can't I override the name as I can with position and rotation without overriding he whole data object?

Tags: linked-data, data-blocks, library-overrides

I have a number of assets in a separate blend file. I drag them into a 'staging' blend file to use them. My default import for that asset library is Link. After I drag them in I use SHIFT+CLICK to create a library override here on the chain icon of the object section.

[image: image showing the chain icon on the object section]

I can now change the position & rotation of this item in this 'staging' blend file. Fantastic. If I make an edit in the asset file to materials or the mesh, because it's linked it's reflected in the 'staging' blend file. Exactly what everyone wants.

I can't however change the name. The only way I seem to be able to do that is to create a local copy of the 'object block' to change the name. Now when I make edits to the master data in asset file my changes aren't reflected down as simply.

Blender can rename these objects (if I drag in another copy of the same asset it renames it in the form MYOBJECT.001) so there is an override name stored somewhere locally, but it wont let me do it. Interestingly it won't let me drag in an identical copy until I create a library override of the first object.

[image: example of blender renaming objects but not letting me]

Can I create a library override for the name of an object to show up in the outliner, without creating a local copy of the 'object block'?